# How to set AVCaptureVideoDataOutput capture frame size?

Tags: ios, video, avcapturesession

I have a layerRect that show my camera's image like this:

```
CGRect layerRect = [[videoStreamView layer] bounds];
[[[self captureManager] previewLayer] setBounds:layerRect];
[[[self captureManager] previewLayer] setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(layerRect),
                                                              CGRectGetMidY(layerRect))];
[[videoStreamView layer] addSublayer:[[self captureManager] previewLayer]];
```

The `videoStreamView` is the view for me to show video, which is 150x150. But I use `setSampleBufferDelegate` from my `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`, the video frame I get is the whole camera image (1280 * 720). How can I modify it? Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm struggling getting a video to be the same as what was shown on screen.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's controlled by the `AVCaptureSession`'s `sessionPreset` property. I'm still trying to figure out just what each of the preset values means in terms of image size, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solves it?

```
CGRect bounds = view.layer.bounds;
previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
previewLayer.bounds=bounds;
previewLayer.position=CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds));
```

Comment: The previewLayer can show the image, but the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` can't.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:[self.captureManager session]];
newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = bounds;//CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x, bounds.origin.y, bounds.size.height, bounds.size.width);
```

Comment: My `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` is no problem, but the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` is not success.

Answer (score -1):

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *prevLayer;
```

Then:

```
self.prevLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession: self.captureSession];
    self.prevLayer.frame = yourRect;
[self.view.layer addSublayer: self.prevLayer];
```